# How order ng-repeat with my custom option?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

i have data :

```
{
   games":[
       {
          "id":"AAA",
          "categories":["1"],
          "name":"Joker Double Up"
       },
       {
          "id":"BBB",
          "categories":["1"],
          "name":"Joker Wild Up"
       },
       {
          "id":"CCC",
          "categories":["3"],
          "name":"Joker Wild Double Up"
       },
       {
          "id":"DDD",
          "categories":["2"],
          "name":"Wild Double Up"
       },
       {
          "id":"EEE",
          "categories":["2"],
          "name":"Joker Wild Double"
       }
   ]
}
```

(its come from back end ,so i cant do edit here)

And show it with ng-repeat here:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in gamesList | groupBy: 'categories' "> ...  

 </div>
```

I grouped this games per groups by 'category' and now want to order this groups.
(i use angular 1.6 also angular-filter)

I want order this data by "id" like this 
 1. CCC 
 2. AAA 
 3. BBB 
 4. EEE 
 5. DDD 
 
(its has not any logical statement for js orderBy , just custom order)

I know that i cant find some parameter for orderBy function , because its already custom order . How can i realize this ?

Comment: What ist the logical pattern you want to sort by?

Comment: I want order this data by "id" like this 
1. CCC 
2. AAA 
3. BBB 
4. EEE 
5. DDD 

Now it orders randomly.

Comment: I read that. Can you express the order in a logical statement (depending on ID, category, ...)=

Comment: Its already custom order, and haven't any logical statement

Comment: code follows logic `(if a < b then .... otherwise ...)`. If your list order has none, how can you expect to code for it?

Comment: I understand that already , but in this case my order should look like this --> CCC,AAA,BBB,EEE,DDD . I cant find any logical statement for this order because this orderlist just client opinion.

Comment: So its cant be orderBy : 'category' , or orderBy: 'Id' , or somethink else ...

Comment: the built in `orderBy` filter does not work with objects, as per the documentation:  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat.  "If you are hitting any of these limitations, the recommended workaround is to convert your object into an array that is sorted into the order that you prefer before providing it to `ngRepeat`. You could do this with a filter such as `toArrayFilter` or implement a `$watch` on the object yourself."

Comment: toArray works very slowly , data is so big (nearly 2000items with many attributes) . I grouped this games into groups (groupBy: 'categories') , and after that i want order this groups like my orderlist but dont know how ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the program to sort your items, you have to provide a logical criteria to sort by. A simple solution can be to add a index property to your items and use this for Angular's `orderBy` function.

```
{
games":[
   {
      "id":"AAA",
      "categories":["1"],
      "name":"Joker Double Up",
      "index": 2
   },
   {
      "id":"BBB",
      "categories":["1"],
      "name":"Joker Wild Up",
      "index": 3
   },
   {
      "id":"CCC",
      "categories":["3"],
      "name":"Joker Wild Double Up",
      "index": 0
   },
   {
      "id":"DDD",
      "categories":["2"],
      "name":"Wild Double Up",
      "index": 5
   },
   {
      "id":"EEE",
      "categories":["2"],
      "name":"Joker Wild Double",
      "index": 4
   }
]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer , but i cant add 'index' to my items , because i get it from another API .

Comment: Maybe there is some way orderBy my array ? and then add  array with my orderlist {  'CCC' , 'AAA' , 'BBB' , 'EEE' , 'DDD' }

Comment: hmmm, how can i explain in controller ?

Comment: An 'orderList' 'which you always have to adapt, when the list from the server changes? Imho not a good idea. Why do you use a 'ng-repeat' at all? If you have 5 elements that need to get displayed in this static layout, where is the benefit of a generic 'ng-repeat'?

Comment: In really i get from server more then 2000 games . 5 games just for visalisation) . I grouped this games into groups (groupBy: 'categories') , and after that i want order this groups like my orderlist .